# Informatica Folder Last access time

Tags: informatica

Is there any Informatica repository object that stores the information about the Folder last access timestamp?
I checked opb_subject table but it contains info on creation time only.
Reason for this is that I want to clear up all the unused development folders to save memory.

Answer (score 0):

None that I'd know of. Rename them, wait some time. In case of no alerts do a backup and remove. Alert will come ;)

Comment: Well I can't do that even if I wanted to.

Comment: Can you review Repository logs? Any login attempts should be visible there.

Answer (score 0):

The opb tables store runtimes for workflows and tasks... you can trace back this way ... dont have the query I use to hand but you can modify the example posted here https://network.informatica.com/message/83889 by Gopinath K... or the query Nico Heinz posted may even suffice